# Code wont ignore numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a simple code but I tried doing a for loop within a if statement but it ended up reversing the numbers  and the sentence. I do not know what I am missing or what im doing wrong I commented out the part I was working to get that part to work.

The code is supposed to do this:
a FUNCTION which takes in a String as a parameter and returns a Pig Latin version of that string.  The program should be able to :

1. Handle punctuation
2. Ignore numbers (i.e. if “500” is passed in, “500” is passed back)
3. Handle multiple sentences

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the word or sentence to convert into Pig Latin");
    string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string pigLatin = PigLatin(sentence);
    Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);
}

static string PigLatin(string sentence)
{
    string letter = sentence.ToLower();
    string firstLetter, restWord, vowels = "AEIOUaeio";
    //int numbers;
    int current;
    foreach (string word in sentence.Split())
    {
        firstLetter = sentence.Substring(0, 1);
        restWord = sentence.Substring(1, sentence.Length - 1);
        current = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);
        if (current == -1)
        {
            sentence = restWord + firstLetter + "ay";

        }
        //for (int numbers = 0; numbers ; numbers++)
        //{
        //   sentence += numbers;
        //}

    }
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: can u explain in simple words what's going wrong with an example?

Comment: if i am correct,do u want `sentence` to ignore numbers ? if so,what is ur expected result if `sentence` contains number ?

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you are not manipulating each word in the sentence. `firstLetter = sentence.Substring(0, 1);` ==> `firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);`, and so on.

Comment: @zackraiyan its not ignoring the letters when I tried get it to ignore the sentence

Comment: I want it to look like this “Alex, how did you do question 21?”  should translate to “lexAay, owhay idday ouyay oday uestionqay 21?”

Comment: Do you have any functionality that converts to other language?(i see ur code but dont have the time to try it)

Comment: It only converts the words  but it does not recognize punctionality , if I enter something like a question mark it wont show and tries to reverse  numbers

Comment: check out the answer and mark it as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will eliminate all numbers from a `string`/get only the alphabets(letters) from a `string` :

```
 var letters = new String(sentence.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

But i see u also need the number , in this case,do this :

```
 var numbers = new String(sentence.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())
```

So , finally you can do your translation of `letters` and use the `numbers` variable at the end ..

```
 var result = stringAfterTranslation + numbers.ToString();
```

Hope it helps :)